# Implementing a Non-Static Handler for ICommand

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using what I believe to be the ICommand pattern for Xamarin Forms I've implemented this

```
        private Command _onButtonTapCommand = new Command(onButtonTapCommand);
        public ICommand OnButtonTapCommand { get { return _onButtonTapCommand; } }
        private static async void onButtonTapCommand(object obj) {}
```

This all works, but I'd prefer not to have the handler method be static.
Removing static generates the compile error that you'd expect: the field initializer can't reference the non-static method.
Is there a different pattern that I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to simply initialize the Command in the constructor.

```
private Command _onButtonTapCommand;
        public ICommand OnButtonTapCommand { get { return _onButtonTapCommand; } }
        private async void onButtonTapCommand(object obj);

public YourClass()
{
    _onButtonTapCommand = new Command(onButtonTapCommand();
}
```

Comment: That works! But why is it different? I always thought that initializing a local variable in-line is equivalent to doing it in the Constructor.  Clearly not.

Comment: For primitive types it is. Complex types it’s not :)